# How to limit legend to show only the features currently visible in the view?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, legend, map-service

Using ArcGIS Server JavaScript API v4.x and the [Legend Widget](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Legend.html), is it possible to limit the legend to only those features which are currently visible?

For example, in the [Legend Widget Sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=widgets-legend), only show the green High School classes when zoomed in to this extent:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, the Legend widget doesn't work that way.  It is based off the layer's renderer.

> "Labels and their corresponding symbols depend on the values set in
> the Renderer of the layer."

*-- From https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Legend.html*

If you really wanted that behavior, I guess in theory you could update the renderer each time the map changes, but that doesn't seem like a great idea. A slightly better option might be to create your own legend-like display that looks at the currently visible features and updates dynamically as the map extent changes.

Comment: Hi Bjorn - does the new [hideLayersNotInCurrentView](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Legend.html#hideLayersNotInCurrentView) option change this answer? `When data from a layer is not visible in the view, the layer's legend information will be hidden.`